# Apps Script Prompt to react to 'Enter', or HTML Confirm

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to get a prompt in a spreadsheet using Apps Script, where the OK is blue and you can just hit Enter (and esc. for cancel).

I tried playing with HTML's Confirm with HTML Service, which would work great, but so far I can't seem to get it to work without an additional UI pop-up of sort. Plus, I don't know how I would then register what was selected by the user (OK or CANCEL), as that needs to determine what Apps Script does next. Is there a way to transfer a variable from an HTML file to be used in the script?

p.s. The reason why I need this and not the native Alert or Prompt, is because it takes two Tab clicks to get to the OK button, or you just need to use the mouse. It's for a very repetitive task, and it ends up being a huge amount of extra clicks.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether that will satisfy you, but using a sidebar panel to show the "OK/Cancel" buttons could do the job. You can display the task/question via toast message (so that you do not lose the browser's focus on the sidebar's buttons, as it would happen with modal boxes). Then, since the sidebar is being displayed all the time, you could just press enter or tab and enter to choose the previously focused "OK" or "Cancel".

I am not entirely sure how to connect the main function, toast message and OK/Cancel panel, but I guess that storing some data for example in the sheet itself could do the job.

For example: you have "D5" cell coordinates stored somewhere in a sheet and you run function. Toast asks you if you want to modify D5 (using the stored coordinates). If you select yes, a function runs, takes the coordinates and proceeds.

That's pretty complicated and probably monstrously uneffective but if your job  is really so repetitive, it may save some time.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AAUmExq030wJtL61zGAlmc_T8pljElC1gcBLLmpd5Go/edit#gid=0)'s an example sheet (HTML code is taken from some of my old scripts) and code for GS and HTML is also available below.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
  .setTitle('a test');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showSidebar(html)
  .createMenu('——MENU')
  .addItem('Test toast', 'openDialog')
  .addToUi();
}

// ok/cancel functions
function func_ok(){
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('ok');
  // do something
}

function func_cancel(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('cancel');
  // do something
}

// toast function
function openDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('you can display some information here and confirm in via the panel');
}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<div style='font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #323232 0%,#ffffff 100%);padding-bottom:100%'>

<section style='background:#FFE599'>
<button onclick="google.script.run.func_ok();">OK</button>
<button onclick="google.script.run.func_cancel();">Cancel</button>
</section>

</div>


<!-- stylesheet -->
<style>

h4 {
margin:auto auto 10px auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.3);
padding:3px 10px;
background: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.1);
text-align:center
}

button {
background: #E5E5E5;
border:none;
border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
border-radius:2px;
padding:3px 4px;
margin:4px 10%;
width:80%
}

button:hover {
background:#efefef;
cursor:pointer
}

section {
padding-bottom:5%;
margin: 0 2% 5% 2%;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow:0 1px 2px 1px #111111;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I think it will be challenging to get this to work because the focus is constantly on the spreadsheet and the prompt would appear as a result of a value in the spreadsheet, so either way the focus won't be on the sidebar.

Comment: I ended up finding a strange solution, but seems to work:
I'm using HtmlService to open a dialog with an `html` OK button auto-focused. Because HtmlService Ui's do not halt the script from continuing, I set up a separate `whenClicked(doThis)`  function, where `doThis` is a variable that evaluates to true under specific conditions.

Comment: This solved about 75% of cases, but the remaining 25% now required extra clicks because the focus wasn't on the ESC button... So what I did was I added a `Utilities.sleep`, allowing me to hit OK for only 3 seconds, after which another dialog opens running a `<script>google.script.host.close()</script>`, which results in closing the original dialog. In a way it's even better, I don't even need to hit ESC. Convoluted somehow, but does the trick :)

Comment: The last trick with ESC is great :) About the HtmlService - I thought about auto focusing as well, but for some reason when I checked it, I couldn't force it to autocous the proper element and so I abandoned it. Anyways, great and fruitful ideas, congratulations!

Comment: Thank you! It was a fun introduction to html, I didn't even know that you can autofocus on something... haha). Here's how I got it to focus: `<input type="button" class="red" autofocus value="OK!"onclick="google.script.run.whenClicked('+doThis+');google.script.host.close()"/>`